# Having problems building Qt-Static 5.3.2

Tags: c++, windows, qt, powershell

So I wanted to build Qt Static so my application can run w/o the Qt. debugger following the instructions from the link below.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW

The script I used is called Windows-build-qt-static.ps1.

I executed the script in Windows Powershell as instructed and change the configure line parameters to build with 5.3.2 as oppose to 5.2.

15 minutes into the build I got the following error.

```
mingw32-make1: Target ‘install’ not remade because of errors.
mingw32-make1: Leaving directory ‘C:/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2/qtbase’
Makefile:75: recipe for target ‘module-qtbase-install_subtargets’ failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-install_subtargets] Error 2
mingw32-make: Target ‘install’ not remade because of errors.
```

I don’t fully understand what goes on into the building of a developer’s environment so any advice on solving this issue would be appreciated.

Also if you have any alternative methods for building a static QT application for release let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I solved it after I installed Python and ActivePerl and set the variable PATH.